# Binding Button command which inside ListView Item WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ListView that outputs the content. total of 4 columns: Chapter number, title, edit button, delete button
When you click on the button, you need to get the element where it is located (for example, the Chapter number or Chapter name). I tried to do binding via the ListView name and via FindAncestor, but nothing happened.
Please help solve the problem or point out errors

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="TableOfContents" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContentList}" 
                              Background="{x:Null}" Width="600"
                              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"                              
                              BorderBrush="{x:Null}">

                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                                    Command="{Binding Command}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TableOfContents, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="50">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThemeID}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="30"
                                                       TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="460">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThemeName}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="20"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="40">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button Content="" ToolTip="Редактировать"
                                                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="18"
                                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                                                      AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}},
                                                                      Path=TableOfContentsPageViewModel.EditTheme}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="40">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button Content="❌" ToolTip="Удалить"
                                                    Foreground="Black" FontSize="18"
                                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                                                      AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}},
                                                                      Path=TableOfContentsPageViewModel.DeleteTheme}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>


                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
class TableOfContentsPageViewModel:BaseViewModel, IPageViewModel
    {
        public string SearchedChapter { get; set; }
        public Visibility CanEdit { get; set; } = Visibility.Hidden;
        public Theme SelectedTheme { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Theme> ContentList { get; set; }

        public TableOfContentsPageViewModel()
        {
            ContentList = new ObservableCollection<Theme>(TrainSQL_Commands.GetAllThemes());
            CanEdit = CurrentUser.Role == "Administrator" ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        private ICommand _editTheme;
        public ICommand EditTheme
        {
            get
            {
                return _editTheme ?? (_editTheme = new RelayCommand(x =>
                  {
                      MessageBox.Show("Edit theory");
                  }));
            }
        }

        private ICommand _deleteTheory;
        public ICommand DeleteTheme
        {
            get
            {
                return _deleteTheory ?? (_deleteTheory = new RelayCommand(x =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Delete theory");
                }));
            }
        }
    }
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpROA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

RelativeSource binds to the control itself, not via the DataContext (which make sense when you think about it). You're currently binding to the Path `TableOfContentsPageViewModel.DeleteTheme`, you need to change that to `DataContext.TableOfContentsPageViewModel.DeleteTheme`.

Comment: YES!  I should have written it a little differently. In this case everything works


Command="{Binding ElementName=TableOfContents, Path=DataContext.DeleteTheme}"